# aws-sdk using old ACCESS_KEY_ID

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently changed my aws credentials in my `.env` file

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
```

However on every `s3.getSignedUrl` request, the SDK uses the previous (root) credentials.

```
  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.end();
    }
    console.log(data)       <---------------
    const returnData = {
      signedRequest: data,
      awsImageUrl: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${imageName}`
    };
    res.json(returnData);
    res.end();
  });
```

This logs

```
https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my-pic.png?AWSAccessKeyId=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYContent-Type=image%2Fpng&Expires=SOMEDATE&Signature=SOMESIGNATURE&x-amz-acl=public-read
```

`YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY` is the previous, root credentials

Is it possible that the SDK caches this data?

If so how do I invalidate it?

Or have I overlooked something in code?

Comment: What is this .env file you refer to?

Comment: The format for ~/.aws/credentials, if that's what you're using, is aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key (lower case).

Comment: @jarmod I literally just saw that by printing out `console.log(s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params))`. Naively thought SDK was using .env file. Gonna answer my question shortly

Comment: @softcode Yeah that's what I guessed , check my answer you should be able to update the file with the refresh() method as documented. :)

Answer (score 1):

[AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html)

> **Expiring and Refreshing Credentials**
>
> Occasionally credentials can expire in the middle of a long-running
>   application. In this case, the SDK will automatically attempt to
>   refresh the credentials from the storage location if the Credentials
>   class implements the refresh() method.
>
> If you are implementing a credential storage location, you will want
>   to create a subclass of the Credentials class and override the
>   refresh() method. This method allows credentials to be retrieved from
>   the backing store, be it a file system, database, or some network
>   storage. The method should reset the credential attributes on the
>   object.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers my question, since I have explicitly swapped the credentials myself. I am not asking whether they have expired. What am I missing from your answer?

Comment: Are you sure the credentials are not loaded from any file and only loading from the env.? What OS are you running? What version of the SDK are you running? How do you initialize the credentials? Have you tried deleting the env. completely and see what happens? Have you tried restarting your server? Update your question with details so we can help solving your issue easier.

Comment: Ok just identified the issue will write up, thank you for raising the right questions

Comment: NP, I don't know why you would use the env. method , if you have chosen to do so yourself for your own reasons, otherwise I strongly suggest you go with IAM roles if you are running your servers hosted at AWS, it is much easier to manage and configure without any mess and also gives you a better security control.

Comment: am actually on Heroku using its own config vars in prod, this question is specifically for local dev setup

Answer (score 1):

When seeking credentials, the JavaScript and Node SDKs use the [`AWS.CredentialProviderChain`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CredentialProviderChain.html).

The [default credentials providers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CredentialProviderChain.html#defaultProviders-property) are:

```
AWS.CredentialProviderChain.defaultProviders = [function () {
  return new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');
}, function () {
  return new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AMAZON');
}, function () {
  return new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials();
}, function () {
  if (AWS.ECSCredentials.prototype.getECSRelativeUri() !== undefined) {
    return new AWS.ECSCredentials();
  }
  return new AWS.EC2MetadataCredentials();
}]
```

Thus, it looks in the following locations:

- Environment credentials
- `~/.aws/credentials` file
- `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`
- Instance metadata